# Undoing specific iptables ip/port restriction

Tags: iptables

Say I add the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DROP
```

This allows localhost to access port 4444 then blocks all other IPs from accessing port 4444...

I now want to undo these previous iptables commands. What is the easiest way to "undo" that? e.g. allow all ips to access port 4444 again.

Comment: `man iptables` is your friend

Answer (score 7):

From `iptables --help`:

```
--delete  -D chain      Delete matching rule from chain
--delete  -D chain rulenum
                Delete rule rulenum (1 = first) from chain
```

So, just issue:

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DROP
```

Alternatively, you can delete by line numbers. First, get the line numbers of your rules:

```
iptables -L INPUT -n --line-numbers
```

Then, delete:

```
iptables -D INPUT <line_number>
```

Comment: oh wow. so just the same command, switching -A to -D. Didn't expect it to be so intuitive. thanks!

Comment: It's amazing what happens when one reads the documentation. Hint, hint. :)